# What is wrong with the following quadratic equation code?

Tags: python, variables, math, floating-point, quadratic

I am trying to make a program that converts standard form quadratic equations to factored form using the quadratic formula, but I'm getting an error on the part where I begin to do math. It seems like it has a problem with the floats I am using, but I do not know why, nor do I know how to fix it.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josef\Documents\Python\standardFactored.py", line 25, in <module>
    rightS = b^2-4*a*c
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'
```

---

Here's the code:

```
print("This program will convert standard form quadratic equations to "
      "factored form. ax^2+bx+c --> a(x+ )(x+ )")

while True:
    try:
        a = float(raw_input("a = "))
        break
    except:
        print("that is not a valid number")

while True:
    try:
        b = float(raw_input("b = "))
        break
    except:
        print("that is not a valid number")

while True:
    try:
        c = float(raw_input("c = "))
        break
    except:
        print("that is not a valid number")

rightS = b^2-4*a*c
try:
    math.sqrt(rightS)
except:
    ("There is no factored for for this equation")
    quit()
```

Comment: The operator "^" does not do what you think it does. ^ is called exclusive or. You want to use ** for exponentiation (b**2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` operator probably doesn't do what you expect. It's a binary XOR, or e**X**clusive **OR** operator. The XOR operator doesn't work with floating point numbers, thus producing the error. The error basically says it can't do the operation on two floats. With exponents, use a double asterisk. See the Python operators [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com//python/python_basic_operators.htm).

Example, a to the power b is:

```
a ** b
```

In your case, it would be:

```
rightS = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
```

Comment: No problem @JosefBuchko!